# How do I mock an IP address in cucumber/capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Cucumber and Capybara and I'd like a way to simulate the request IP address, like this:

```
Given the request ip address is "10.1.2.3"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by passing the IP address in an environment variable:

```
  When /^the request ip address is "([^\"]*)"$/ do |ip_address|
    ENV['RAILS_TEST_IP_ADDRESS'] = ip_address
  end
```

application_controller.rb:

```
  before_filter :mock_ip_address

  def mock_ip_address
    if Rails.env == 'cucumber' || Rails.env == 'test'
      test_ip = ENV['RAILS_TEST_IP_ADDRESS']
      unless test_ip.nil? or test_ip.empty?
        request.instance_eval <<-EOS
          def remote_ip
            "#{test_ip}"
          end
        EOS
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm on rails 3.1 and I had to change remote_ip to ip.  This works well with the rubygeocoder.com gem.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: This is cool and was useful. But a note to other readers: best to monkey patch the ApplicationController by opening it with a file like `spec/support/remote_ip_monkey_patch.rb`. It's cleaner and nicer looking.

Answer (score 6):

My mix of Leventix's and Ramon's solutions:

**spec/support/remote_ip_monkey_patch.rb**

```
module ActionDispatch
  class Request

    def remote_ip_with_mocking
      test_ip = ENV['RAILS_TEST_IP_ADDRESS']

      unless test_ip.nil? or test_ip.empty?
        return test_ip
      else
        return remote_ip_without_mocking
      end
    end

    alias_method_chain :remote_ip, :mocking

  end
end
```

Comment: Would you please tell me what kind of object `ENV['RAILS_TEST_IP_ADDRESS']` is so I can create it? Is it just a string? I'll try `'123.123.123.123'` or something.